# request downloading a file basing on criterias from javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, download

I've got a web application (php/symfony2 - but it doesn't matter here) with heavy AJAX usage and quite a lot of javascript in the client side layer. The interface enables the user to filter the data he wants to display (periods, checkboxes, selects, etc.) and basing on those choice, a POST request goes to the server side for data and JSON is returned through AJAX.

Now, I want to add a functionality to download the data file basing on the criterias/filters that reside in the javascript layer - and I'm not sure how should I do it.

Let's say I've got a `<a href="some_action_url">` tag that - if I click - it downloads the file. I know how to do all the server-side stuff. But I don't know how to pass the criteria parameters from javascript to the server-side controller a using the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Put the criteria in the URL's "query" part?

Comment: @Passerby: you mean to make it a GET action with a query string. But is it possible to create a POST action?

Comment: Yes, use a "hidden" `<form method="POST">` and construct `<input type="hidden">` inside the form upon clicking the link.